# Group Private Messaging System

Tags: php, mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm coding a private message system, which works perfectly. I need to write a SQL query for group messages, and that message should come up only once. In short I want a "conversation view" just like Facebook, only show the latest message either it is sent or recieved. Script in backend is PHP in private messaging system.

I attached a screen shot:

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the attached query I'm using.

Testing demo is uploaded on this address: [http://developers89.byethost14.com/messages/](http://developers89.byethost14.com/messages)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: For group messaging, design your db structure first. You could move the receiver_id to a separate table, so you have `email_recipient (email_id (fk), recip_order, receiver_id (fk))`. The recipient order is an ordinal that lists the receivers in order (useful if you render them in a 'To' field) and 'receiver_id' is, of course, who is to receive this email. This will permit you to send an email to many users - one row per recipient per email.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    conversation
WHERE   (LEAST(sender_ID, receiverID), GREATEST(sender_ID, receiverID), date)
        IN
        (
            SELECT  LEAST(sender_ID, receiverID) x, 
                    GREATEST(sende_ID, receiverID) y,
                    MAX(date) max_date
            FROM    conversation
            GROUP   BY x, y
        )
        AND '$uid' IN (sender_ID, receiverID)
//      AND other conditions if you have  ...
//      ORDER BY ...
//      LIMIT ...
```